# Working with Swing Timers

Tags: java, swing

Why is the following code not working?
I want to create an application that draws a BufferedImage onto a JPanel. So as soon as you start the program you see it painting the image. I learned that you need Swing timers for that so I tried implementing them. Now I want the program to sleep after each horizontally drawn pixel line x. So after repaint() I want the JPanel to stop painting for some Milliseconds and after that it should draw the next line. But what have I done wrong?

Hint: method createPicture provides a matrix with int values that are turned into colors.

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    int[][] matrix = new int[1920][1080];
    private BufferedImage image;
    int x=0,y=0;

    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              if(y==1079||x==1919){  //as soon as the image is ready             
                  ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
              }else{
              for(y=0;y<1080;y++){
               for(x=0;x<1920;x++){
                   image.setRGB(x,y,matrix[x][y]);
               }repaint();
               //I want it to sleep here
               }
              } 
              }
      }; 

    public ImagePanel() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        image = new BufferedImage(1920,1080, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
         createPicture(1920,1080);
          new Timer(200, taskPerformer).start();
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want the program to sleep after each horizontally drawn pixel line x.

When you use a `Timer` all the code in the `ActionListener` is executed every time the `Timer` fires (and you don't want to use sleep() in a listener). So you can't execute the two loops inside the Timer.

Instead what you need to do is only increment the "y" value of the image in the listener and then paint all the pixels for that row. So you only need a single loop.

The code might look something like:

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() 
{
    int y = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        for(x=0;x<1920;x++)
        {
            image.setRGB(x,y,matrix[x][y]);
        }

        repaint();

        y++;

        if (y >= ???)
            ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
    }
};
```

Note you should also not be hardcoding the x/y value maximums. Instead you can use the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods of the `BufferedImage`.

Also, when you first create the BufferedImage you will need to paint its background otherwise pixels you haven't changed will be black.

Comment: Ah I see, so you use the Timer as the for-loop. I didnt know that the Timer always exectues its actionPerformed method over and over until it has been stopped. I works perfectly know. Thank you :)